# WordPress creating images if uploaded image is greater than 960px on one side?

Tags: theme-development, images, uploads, media

I'm creating a new theme and have modified the media settings. From the *Settings > Media* page, all sizes are marked as 0x0 so they will not be produced.

[image: Media Settings wordpress]

I am creating only 1 custom thumbnail in my *functions.php* file. In total I should be expecting only 2 images uploaded to Wordpress (the original file and the *post-page-thumb*)

[image: functions.php screenshot]

After uploading an image through the media library (test1.jpg), I see that there is an additional image being created by Wordpress 768x960 when I go in FileZilla.

[![filezilla][3]][3]

My *functions.php* also includes the ability to view custom images when adding media to posts/pages (see above), however, this additional size is not available from the drop down (only the original and thumbnail created).

[![add media][4]][4]

My assumption was that WordPress internally does this somewhere for images that are as large as the one I upload (1600x2000). I don't have any plugins activated.

I tested two additional images: test2.jpg (at 768x960) and test3.jpg (at 600x750). test2.jpg still created the additional 768x960 image, while test3.jpg didnt.

[![new files][5]][5]

Does anyone know what can be causing this issue or a way to fix? 
Is this an issue with WordPress 4.6.1? I've never experienced it before.

```
New user so can't include more than two links, but all are viewable here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQOo6.png [1]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/05ZRm.png [2]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiOLA.png [3]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJwSU.png [4]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZl69.png [5]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress v4.4 [introduced an additional image size](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/11/10/responsive-images-in-wordpress-4-4/) named `medium_large` which is is 768px wide by default, with no height limit. There is no UI for the `medium_large` but the size can be changed by updating the options:

```
/**
 * Updates the medium_large image size. 
 * It's only necessary to execute this code once.
 * Ideally you'd want some kind of UI to allow the dimensions to be specified by the user.
 */
function wpse238808_update_image_size_medium_large() {
    update_option( 'medium_large_size_w', 0 );
    update_option( 'medium_large_size_h', 0 );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse238808_update_image_size_medium_large' );
```

Changing `medium_large`'s width and height to `0` like you've done with the other image sizes will prevent the additional images from being generated.

Comment: Thank you. I applied the code changes and its working correctly after testing. I looked up the new features for WP 4.4 and saw that they added it in for their adaptive design.